# SVN workflow/lifecycle using VisualSVN server, TortoiseSVN, Ankhsvn plugin

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have just started getting svn to my life.

I was told that a good start is to go the triplet "VisualSVN server, TortoiseSVN, Ankhsvn plugin" for VS development.

After spending some time with them i am still at confusion over the workflow.

1. I can do all my work from within Visual Studio and VisualSVN server. So why do i need a svn client like Tortoisesvn? And if i have to use them together what is the proper use for each of them?
2. I have solutions that rely on other projects "layers" (DAL,Business layer). I reference these projects directly to my UI solution. Do i have to change that strategy to accommodate for better svn management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why do i need a svn client like Tortoisesvn?

If you don't know how it works under the hood, you can't identify, diagnose and describe problem smartly. It's just more reliable way to have knowledge about processes at the lower level, than "black-boxed" VS+Ankhsvn ("project","press button","select in menu"), i.e about Subversion-specific aspects (working copy, properties, basic operations).
In order to have this possibilities, you have to have *any* standalone SVN-client, TortoiseSVN is just good choice for it's power and GUI for CLI-powerless Windows users

> Do i have to change that strategy to accommodate for better svn management?

If you know, how these references reflected at ordinary file-level, you can have own answer (I have not any VS experience and can't predict it)

Comment: So if i manage the basic stuff from within VS+Ankhsvn i will have to refresh tortoise every time? or tortoise will be automatically aware and provide me with extra info by using its tools?

Comment: @e4rthdog - will be, on working with WC of your project